# how to place icon to every jquery ui autocomplete without any elemernt injection by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm struck with a problem i have a big project having global `css` with this `css` i want to place `icon` to every `autocomplete` **so that it gives clue to users**

**it should something look like below one:**

```css
.icon:before{
    position: relative;
    content: "V";
    color: red;
    right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

**Note:** `<span class="icon"></span>` which i cannot inject to every `autocomplete`  globally with javascript or jquery. with `css` only i have to achieve desired result

**below is my sample elements to achieve above desired result:**

JSFIddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cS2bL/66/ (Working)

```js
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"john",
"khair",
"compton",
"Jordan",
"Micheal",
"Peter"
];
$( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

```css
.ui-widget{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.float-right{
  float: right;
}

.float-left{
  float: left;
}

.icon:before{
    position: relative;
    content: "V";
    color: red;
    right: 17px;
}

/* tried for below element */

.ui-autocomplete-input:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: 'V';
  color:red;
  
}

/* tried for above element */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input class="tags">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input class="tags" style="width:130px;">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">

<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input class="tags" style="width:140px;">

<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input class="tags" style="width:100px;">

</div>


<div class="floated-elements ui-widget">
   <div class="float-right">
       <label for="tags">Search: </label>
       <input class="tags" style="width:300px;">
   </div>
   
    <div class="float-left">
        <label for="tags">Search: </label>
       <input class="tags" style="width:50px;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you ask how can I can I add icon *to 1000 inputs*, the answer is [like this using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/monim67/cS2bL/82/). If you ask how to add icon *without adding any HTML* i.e adding a pseudo element to input, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669).

Comment: nice solution even though, adding `1000` times `after(icon)` would not borther me. please post your solution!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want **to add an icon in the textbox that gives clue to users**, I suggest that adding an background image as an icon to achieve it.

```css
input.ui-autocomplete-input {
  background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini-4/48/paper-plane-icon.png") right 4px center no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 80%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px 24px 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input"><br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input"><br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input"><br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
```

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo element like `:after`, `:before` can not be used with input elements. It can used with container elements which can have child.

So you can use pseudo element with `label` before the inputs. Since all `label` and `input` are not same in width you can use icon in first of `input` instead of last.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "john",
    "khair",
    "compton",
    "Jordan",
    "Micheal",
    "Peter"
  ];
  $(".tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.icon:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "V";
  color: red;
  right: 17px;
}

/* try below element */

.ui-widget label::after {
    color: red;
    content: "V";
    margin: 3px 0 0 4px;
    position: absolute;
}

.ui-autocomplete-input {
    padding-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.css">

<h1>
  Same result without any span for icon
</h1>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags" style="width:130px;">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags" style="width:140px;">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags" style="width:100px;">
</div>
<div class="floated-elements ui-widget">
  <div class="float-right">
    <label for="tags">Search: </label>
    <input class="tags" style="width:300px;">
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <label for="tags">Search: </label>
    <input class="tags" style="width:50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** `<span class="icon"></span>` which i cannot inject to every `autocomplete` globally with javascript or jquery. with css only i
>   have to achieve desired result

OK, but you could at least add a *custom* class (name) to the *immediate* parent of the `autocomplete` field/`input`??

See below where I added `tags-wrap` class to the `input` container.

```css
.icon:before,
.tags-wrap:after{
    position: relative;
    content: "V";
    color: red;
    right: 17px;
}

/* There should be no .icon in a .tags-wrap; but just in case.. */
.tags-wrap .icon:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-wrap">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
  <!-- This shouldn't be here; but just for the demo purposes... -->
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>

<div class="tags-wrap">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
  <!-- No .icon here -->
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <!-- Add the 'tags-wrap' class to the input's immediate parent -->
  <span class="tags-wrap">
    <label for="tags">Search: </label>
    <input class="tags">
  </span>
</div>

<!-- Inline tests -->
<span class="tags-wrap">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
</span>
<span class="tags-wrap">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input class="tags">
</span>
```

---

If you don't want to *manually* add the `tags-wrap` class, you can use jQuery like so:

```
// Automatically add the 'tags-wrap' class to the immediate parent of the
// autocomplete input fields.
$('.tags').parent(':not(:has(.icon))')
    .addClass('tags-wrap');
```

Demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/2c9pxL7o/

Comment: Well actually, this will only work if the parent/container contains only one pair of *`autocomplete` input and its label (the "Search:" text)* - there's one input that fails here: http://jsfiddle.net/2c9pxL7o/ ...

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit your HTML you wrap your input with your `label` you dont need a for/id then AND you can use after.

`::after` can only be used on container elements(closing ones)
for example `<input/>` and `<img/>` cant have an `::after` via css

**Example**

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  content: 'V';
  color:red;
  
}
```

```html
<label>Search: 
  <input type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: i don't want to wrap each and every input with label, as my project is having more than 1000 input. i can't do as i'm trying?

Comment: @skBangalore well, in this case I dont see any way to do this with pure css